# docker desktop windows won't install docker daemon for wsl2

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

- [x] I have tried with the latest version of my channel (Stable or Edge)
- [x] I have uploaded Diagnostics
- Diagnostics ID: 8C2E2B56-0E86-4E49-BAF5-B06DB3F99738/20200712115912

#### Expected behavior

`sudo service docker` command ran on wsl2 (4.19.121-microsoft-standard) should print service status

#### Actual behavior

`sudo service docker` command prints `docker: unrecognized service`

#### Information

- Windows Version:  20161.1000, Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.16201.0.0
- Docker Desktop Version: 2.3.0.3 (45519)
- Are you running inside a virtualized Windows e.g. on a cloud server or on a mac VM: nope

I followed instructions in [docker documentation page for wsl](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/) so docker can installed to my windows, and checked the command `docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started` on ubuntu running successfully, but the `service` command won't work as described above.

#### Steps to reproduce the behavior

1. follow the instructions in [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/)
2. `sudo service docker` on wsl2 ubuntu